# How to render a paperclip as unicode character in markdown?

Tags: unicode, markdown

According to many sites, in markdown, we can render a Unicode character in Markdown with the following syntax:

```
&#x270F;
```

However, the unicode character for a paperclip is [0x1F4CE](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F4CE#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9C%F0%9F%93%8E%E2%80%9D%20U%2B1F4CE%20Paperclip%20Unicode%20Character) and this does not work:

```
&#x1F4CE;
&#x1f4ce;
&#x270F;
```

Only the latter code can be rendered (its a pencil)

What could be the root cause?

Comment: Those characters render fine in my environment. Just saying _"this does not work"_ is insufficient. What is rendered? Nothing? The replacement character? An empty rectangle? A question mark? As @tchrist has already mentioned in their answer, it's impossible to properly diagnose your problem if you don't provide full details of exactly what you are doing when trying to render those characters. How much detail?.... enough so that others can attempt to emulate what you are doing as closely as possible. Without that information all anyone can do is guess  the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine I know what's going on here, but you really need to provide us with a concrete example of somewhere that what you’ve described “does not work”, so that we can inspect it for errors.

Certainly both of these two:

1. `&#x270F;` rendering ✏ for `✏`.
2. `&#x1F4CE;` rendering  for .

work fine here, at least for most of us. Sometimes, however, little toy computers — meaning cell phones or “handies” — don’t provide good support for the full Unicode repertoire, especially in their glyph-substitution fallback algorithms when a glyph is missing from the currently selected font family or typeface.

Remember that markdown must be translated into literal characters before they can be rendered by a client web browser, and that this translation process is done by a variety of twisty-turn agents all unalike in their ability to correctly handle Unicode’s astral planes, which cannot be represented by UCS-2, only by UTF-32 and UTF-8 and UTF-16. Anything in the processing chain that fumbles that conversion process can yield the class of error you mention.